# ADmob : Places in a square in the center of the screen - Iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, admob

Hy guyz, i'm new with adMob and till now i managed to create a singleton class of admob and calling it as the header and footer of all my view controllers.
 
But the thing is, i am supposed now to create a middle screen advertisement spot in the center of the screen. After reviewing the adMob documentation, i thought it couldn't take place since it is NOT a InterStitial ad and it's not a simple banner ad.

[image]

Any ideas how to create it ?